# How can I offer A-D in an array as the correct answer, as opposed to 0-3?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, indexing

I've just started programming in C# and really struggling on a particular section. I've put together a multiple choice quiz and listed the parameters in an array. The trouble i'm having is how to generate the letters A-D as the correct answer, instead of 0,1,2,3. Can anyone help? I feel like it's so simple but I just can't figure it out. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Also i'd set the answers as integers '0,1,2,3' but now it's not even connecting them to the correct answer :(

I have a 'Question' class containing:

```
public Question(string q, string[] answersList, string typeOfQuestion, int correctAnswer)
```

I then create the question object in the program with

```
new Question("What colour is the sky?", 
    new string[] { "A. Pink", "B. Blue", "C. Purple", "D.Yellow" },
    Question.multipleChoice, B );
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: How are you generating options 0,1,2,3

Comment: In ASCII (and therefore non-portable C), you'd write `'A' + n` where `n` is the number. C# insists on ASCII (although strings are more complex), so it's a matter of checking if this syntax works. (I'm not a C# programmer so can't say much more).

Comment: So I've made a class for the 'questions' with 'public Question(string q, string[] answersList, string typeOfQuestion, int CorrectAnswer)' being the array. In the program, I've then been following this

Comment: @Bathsheba It's similar - you just need to cast to char again -- `(char)('A' + 2)` is `C` for example. C# chars aren't ASCII though...

Comment: post your code together with the question @NewProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little console application that generates letters for items in an array, and takes user input (upper or lowercase) and converts it back to a number.

The key is that 'a' is 65 and 'A' is 97 in ASCII, and that you can convert a number to a letter with `Convert.ToChar(i)`. The console provides the ASCII value, but you can find the ASCII value for and a letter with `(int)Char.GetNumericValue('a');`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q1 = new Question("What colour is the sky?", new string[] { "Pink", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow" }, "multipleChoice", 1);

        AskQuestion(q1);
    }

    private static void AskQuestion(Question q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(q.Prompt);
        for (var i = 0; i < q.AnswersList.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToChar(65 + i)} - {q.AnswersList[i]}");
        }

        var answer = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (answer.KeyChar == 65 + q.CorrectAnswer ||
            answer.KeyChar == 97 + q.CorrectAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong");
        }
    }

    private class Question
    {
        public string Prompt { get; }
        public string[] AnswersList { get;  }
        public string TypeOfQuestion { get; }
        public int CorrectAnswer { get;  }

        public Question(string prompt, string[] answersList, string typeOfQuestion, int correctAnswer)
        {
            this.Prompt = prompt;
            this.AnswersList = answersList;
            this.TypeOfQuestion = typeOfQuestion;
            this.CorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: .Net doesn't use "ASCII" but Unicode (encoded as UTF-16). But the character codes from ASCII (0-127) do have the same meaning in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

you need update class structure then it will be easy to manage

```
 public class Question
{
    public string q { get; set; }
    public List<answersList> answersList { get; set; }
    public string typeOfQuestion { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}
public class answersList
{
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

and for making object

```
 var objQuestion = new Question
        {
            q = "What colour is the sky?",
            CorrectAnswer = 1,
            typeOfQuestion = "5",
            answersList=new List<answersList> { new answersList { answer="xyz", code="a"} }
        };
```

Comment: I don't think a List really helps here. They're great when you need to add and remove items, especially in the middle, but in this example a List doesn't offer anything that you can't do with an array. The length doesn't change after creation, and items are accessed by position.